# Entity Framework: When to use Set<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying understand the basics of Entity Framework and I have a question about the `Set<>` method on `DbContext`. I am using a database first model for the following question.

Let's say I have an `ActivityLog` database which amongst other things I can use to pull out a message (NLog message, for example). I could write some code to pull out all messages like this:

```
using (var entities = new ActivityLogEntities())
    foreach (var log in entities.AcitivityLogs)
        Console.WriteLine(log.Message);
```

However I could also achieve the same thing doing this:

```
using (var entities = new ActivityLogEntities())
    foreach (var message in entities.Set<ActivityLog>().Select(entity => entity.Message))
        Console.WriteLine(message);
```

My question is what is the difference between these two statements? When is it more appropriate to use one over the other? Or is this just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: If you don't have an `ActivityLogs` property, you cannot use the `ActivityLogs` property. That may seem like a useless response, but I have had situations where I needed to access a `DbSet<T>` for a type which intentionally did not have a direct property for the entities of that type. But this does not answer the question of which to use when both are possible.

Comment: @hvd agreed but its pretty rare to have types un-referenced by the context (and its not entirely trivial to do)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Consider `public class Order { public ICollection<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; } } public class OrderLine { } public class Context { public IDbSet<Order> Orders { get; private set; } }`. No extra work is needed to make this work, and it doesn't usually make sense to access `OrderLines` without the orders, so why should I add a `OrderLines` property at the context level?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no significant difference. In the first case, you have something like:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AcitivityLog> AcitivityLogs { get; set; }
}
```

When context is being created, it looks for public `DbSet<T>` read/write-properties, and does this (pseudo-code):

```
dbSetProperty = Set<EntityType>();
```

But, there are cases, when you:

1. don't want to make public properties for all of you entity types;
2. don't know all of the entity types at context's design time.

In these cases `Set<T>` is the only way to get proper entity set.

Comment: I'm guessing in the case of your second example this would only apply to auto generated?

Comment: @Serberuss: no, not only. The one of the benefits of `DbContext` API is that you can build the context dynamically (in contrast of traditional approach with `ObjectContex` and EDM designer). This allows to build data model much more flexible, but it has a side-effect: the list of entity types is not static and the developer of `DbContext` ancestor just can't know about every entity type.

Comment: Unfortunately the second example doesn't work. I following kind of error:
`The entity <type> is not part of the model for the current context.` I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 11):

The only reason i have ever used `Set<T>` is when you are acting on a type you dont know, eg a generic insert.

Heres an example from [my generic repository](https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Repository/blob/master/StaticVoid.Repository.EntityFramework/DbContextRepositoryDataSource.cs):

```
  public void AddOnSave(T entity)
  {
     ctx.Set<T>.Add(entity);
  }
```

Using it for regular stuff just makes the code less readable IMHO

Comment: [`AddOrUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217945(v=vs.113).aspx) ?

Comment: @oCcSking not sure what you mean?

Comment: Actually, I did not understand your answer correctly, confused with the case you are not sure if you add or update then you can use AddOrUpdate

Comment: @oCcSking oh yup, this is not add or update this is dealing with a add method for a generic repository of type T

Answer (score 3):

If your look at the generated `DbContext` class you'll see that `AcitivityLogs` is just a `DbSet<ActivityLog>`.

So they are the same same thing.  It's just the typed definition of your DbSet.