# c# I find .SET in an expression confusing

Tags: c#

I've come across an expression in some code and I can't find any place that explains it.

The code is:

```
public void Create(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Set<T>.Add(entity);
```

where T is a class type

RepositoryContext is a DbContext environment if that matters.  It's the ".Set" I don't get.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that looks wrong to me - it should be Set() - its a method

Comment: [Entity Framework: When to use Set<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984465/entity-framework-when-to-use-set)

Comment: It's a `DbSet<T>` - a data set - code representation of a table in your database ...

Comment: [DbSet<TEntity>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: @pm100: check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#system-data-entity-dbcontext-set-1 - `dbContext.Set<T>()` is very much valid - but you're right - it's a method and thus needs `()` .....

Comment: Side note: while adding "Thanks in afvanced" (note that you did not use the SO favorite spelling) is a statement of style, it is not recommended for posts here - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a method call `Set<T>()` actually - as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-7.0)  `Set` method  creates a `DbSet` for provided entity type:

> Creates a `DbSet<TEntity>` that can be used to query and save instances of `TEntity`.

So it can be used to generically work entities of context. So for example:

```cs
public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities {get;set;}
}

MyAppContext ctx = ...
```

`ctx.Set<MyEntity>` is analogous to `ctx.MyEntities`.

Note that for example documentation mentions usage of this method as [one of the strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#dbcontext-and-dbset) when working with [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) so there is no warnings:

```cs
public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities => Set<MyEntity>();
}
```